# Update records that match like regex from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - `ProductCategories` and `Products`:

```
ProductCategories
---
productid    categoryid
1            
2
3
4


Products
--------
productid    productname
1            Apple
2            Apricot
3            Tomato
4            Watermelon
```

and I would like to populate `categoryid` in table `ProductCategories` in such manner that all products having names starting with `"Ap"` are set to categoryid 1, starting with `"To"` to category 2 and starting with `"Wa"` to category 3 resulting with table `ProductCategories` populated as follows

```
ProductCategories
---
productid    categoryid
1            1
2            1
3            2
4            3
```

I have tried this

```
UPDATE ProductCategories 
SET categoryid = '1' 
WHERE product_id IN 
      (SELECT product_id 
       FROM Products 
       WHERE productname LIKE 'Ap%')
```

but query does nothing. I would have run modified query few times for other options (`"To"`, `"Wa"`, etc) to completely populate `ProductCategories` table.

Answer (score 1):

Please try, if you could, this approach:

```
UPDATE 
    ProductCategories, 
    Products
SET 
    ProductCategories.categoryid = CASE LEFT(UCASE(LTRIM(Products.productname)), 2)
                                      WHEN 'AP' THEN 1
                                      WHEN 'TO' THEN 2
                                      WHEN 'WA' THEN 3
                                      ELSE ProductCategories.categoryid
                                   END
    WHERE 
        ProductCategories.product_id = Products.product_id
```

I assumed that product ID column is named `product_id`